# Understanding aws policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-iam-policy

I have the below IAM policy definied. I am not sure what is the below policy signify. Is the principal pointing to the `root` user or `root` account and any authenticated user associated with the `root` account.

Before raising this question, I have referred to this [Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html).

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:root"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Condition": {}
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a Trust Policy that is attached to an IAM Role.

It is saying that IAM Users in `<account-id>` can assume the IAM Role as long as they have been granted sufficient permission to call `AssumeRole()`.

The reference to `root` is saying that it trusts whatever policies exist in that particular account. So, if an IAM User in that account has been granted permission to call `AssumeRole()`, then the policy will allow it. It's a way of saying "trust whatever that account says".

Comment: Yes this is a trust policy that is attached to an IAM Role. There is no permission added to the role. This role is been assumed by three different roles namely k8s-dev, k8s-admin and k8s-integration. Further the three roles are been assigned to three groups to which the users are added.

Comment: `The reference to root is saying that it trusts whatever policies exist in that particular account. `  Here does the account refers to the `IAM user`?  Does it says, "trust all the policies that the IAM user account" has?

Comment: Yes, it will trust any policies on IAM Users in the reference AWS Account. So, if somebody has permission to call Assume Role on that role, then the role will allow itself to be assumed by them.